# Are tags mysteriously disappearing?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tagging

In the light of Pat's [competition to improve the site](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/918/what-can-you-do-for-bcg), I've been reading, editing and voting on some of the older questions.  I've recently come across two that already had edits saying they were adding a tag, but the tag wasn't on the question:

https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/posts/1497/revisions

https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/posts/1466/revisions

Has anyone else been noticing this, or did ire_and_curses and I make a mistake the first time we edited these questions?

Comment: By the way, thanks for all the reading/editing/voting!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Across the SE network tags that are only used once are [auto-purged after 6 months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92056/shouldnt-so-unused-tags-be-deleted) or so by design.

This is kind of a pain for us, but we have to deal with it.  [Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5379/stop-removing-tags-that-are-only-used-once-in-the-last-6-months) also deals with this on a regular basis.

When I ask a question about a new game I make an attempt to ask two questions about it.  Usually the second question is a bit more lame, but it will keep the tag hanging around.

Comment: Thanks - this is almost certainly the answer.  I'll add another Blokus question, and try and find out a bit more about the Pillars of the Earth!

Comment: I've seen this here too -- a question should almost always have a game-specific tag, so when it doesn't that's a hint.  BH has been having the same problem and one of the mods there came up with [a clever idea](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/400/208) to address it.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - looks like a good idea!

Comment: We recently got auto tag deletion turned off on Arqade.

Answer (score 7):

As of [last summer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127700/1438) (or winter if you are on the other side of the equator from me), tags with wikis are preserved.  So if you tag a question with game that doesn't have any more questions, you may:

1. Write up a tag wiki, or
2. Ask another question.

Either will preserve the tag.