# Let's save our tags!

Tags: discussion, tags

As noted [here](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/930/are-tags-mysteriously-disappearing), tags with only one question are harvested [after about six months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92056/shouldnt-so-unused-tags-be-deleted), leading to questions ending up untagged and hard to find.  I've come across a few of these recently and added them back, just deferring the problem for another half-year.  But the real solution is to ask more questions about these less-common games.

The following game tags currently have only one question.  Can you save them?  If you do, edit this post to claim credit for the tags you save so we know whom to thank.  Or if some of these tags shouldn't exist, please fix them and update this list.

Tags with tag wikis (so somebody cared enough to start colonizing these):

- [star-wars-lcg](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-lcg)

Tags without tag wikis:

- [011](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/011)
- [alexandros](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alexandros)
- [avalon](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avalon)
- [battleship](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battleship)
- [battlestations](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlestations)
- [bismarck](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bismarck)
- [careers](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/careers)
- [circus-imperium](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circus-imperium)
- [day-and-night](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/day-and-night)
- [discwars](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discwars)
- [discworld-ankh-morpork](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discworld-ankh-morpork)
- [dungeon-petz](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeon-petz)
- [dust-warfare](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dust-warfare)
- [elixir](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elixir)
- [encore](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encore)
- [evil-baby-orphanage](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evil-baby-orphanage)
- [flash-point](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash-point)
- [formula-de](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formula-de)
- [gloria-pictoria](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gloria-pictoria)
- [gosu](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gosu)
- [hansa-teutonica](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hansa-teutonica)
- [hawaii](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hawaii)
- [heroclix](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroclix)
- [imperial-2030](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/imperial-2030)
- [infernal-contraption](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infernal-contraption)
- [kings-of-war](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kings-of-war)
- [last-will](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/last-will)
- [mage-wars](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mage-wars)
- [mtg-pauper](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-pauper)
- [mtg-planechase](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-planechase)
- [nuts](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuts)
- [ora-et-labora](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ora-et-labora)
- [parade](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parade)
- [pegs-and-jokers](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pegs-and-jokers)
- [princes-of-florence](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/princes-of-florence)
- [quantum-tic-tac-toe](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-tic-tac-toe)
- [seasons](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seasons)
- [set](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set)
- [somnium](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/somnium)
- [star-wars-gf](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-gf)
- [struggle-for-catan](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/struggle-for-catan)
- [survive-escape-atlantis](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/survive-escape-atlantis)
- [swish](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swish)
- [the-pillars-of-the-earth](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-pillars-of-the-earth)
- [trivial-pursuit](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trivial-pursuit)
- [village](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/village)
- [world-without-end](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-without-end)
- [wrath-of-ashardalon](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wrath-of-ashardalon)
- [zombicide](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zombicide)

In some cases it might make sense to merge these tags (e.g. if the tag here describes an expansion or variant of a game that already has a tag).

**Saved!**

- [empire-builder](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/empire-builder) - by Canageek (later deprecated by [crayon-rail-games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crayon-rail-games), sorry Canageek and thanks for the help!)
- [necron](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/necron) - by Pureferret
- [vinci](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vinci)  - by MonicaCellio
- [dominion-cornucopia](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dominion-cornucopia)   - by Johno
- [rummikub](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rummikub) - by Omega
- [penny-arcade-gamersvsevil](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/penny-arcade-gamersvsevil)  - by Johno
- [talisman](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talisman) - by TheJug
- [american-megafauna](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/american-megafauna) - by ire_and_curses
- [bios-megafauna](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bios-megafauna) - by ire_and_curses
- [in-the-year-of-the-dragon](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/in-the-year-of-the-dragon)  - by Paul Marshall
- [advanced-civilization](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advanced-civilization)
- [blackjack](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blackjack)
- [kids-of-catan](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kids-of-catan)
- [swish](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swish) - by Joe Golton
- [decktet](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decktet)

**Died, leaving orphan wikis behind**
(If you re-create anything on this list, try to find the now-untagged question about it and tag it too.)

**Note:** According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki), single-use tags won't expire any more if they have wikis.  Can someone who can [access the orphan wikis](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/admin/orphan-wikis) below recreate these tags and restore their wikis?  Then we'd just have to find the now-untagged questions.

- [carrom](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carrom)
- [constantinopolis](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constantinopolis)
- [dominos](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dominos)
- [gin-rummy](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gin-rummy) - merge into [rummy](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rummy)?
- [gloom](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gloom)
- [kingdom-builder](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-builder)
- [lost-cities](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lost-cities)
- [neuroshima-hex](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neuroshima-hex)
- [pirate-king](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pirate-king)
- [puzzle-strike](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-strike)
- [republic-of-rome](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/republic-of-rome)
- [rook](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rook)
- [shogun](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shogun)
- [spiel-des-jahres](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spiel-des-jahres)
- [titan](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titan)
- [yggdrasil](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yggdrasil)

Note: I compiled this list via visual scan of the end of the tags list, so it's possible I've missed something or accidentally included something that was being addressed as I typed.  If so, sorry and please note it.

Comment: This is super awesome. :D

Comment: @Aarthi, I stole the idea from another community where you liked it. :-)

Comment: OH MAN NO WONDER! It felt so ~familiar~ I didn't know what to do except express my approval :D

Comment: @Aarthi, I would *never* object to you expressing your approval. :-)  Just wanted to give credit where it's due.

Comment: Ha, fair enough! :D

Comment: shogun is my question and my wiki!! but the game is so easy I can't think of another question to save it :(

Comment: I like this idea a lot! I'd edit more tag wikis, but I don't have the permission. Yet...

Comment: @Johno, I don't either, which just means our edits have to be approved before taking effect.  Dive in!

Comment: Related feature request on MSO: [Do not expire single use tags on Beta sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153357/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-on-beta-sites)

Answer (score 1):

There are [a lot more orphan wikis](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/admin/orphan-wikis) than that. I'll take a look at restoring some, but it's a [tediously manual process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108631/homeless-orphan-tag-wikis-need-original-names-euthanised). I've tried experimenting with recreating the tag, but that doesn't appear to re-link the wiki to its parent, so it looks like the text has to be cut and pasted into the new wiki space.

Also, looking at the text of some of these wikis I am not convinced all that many should be reinstated. At least one user seems to have systematically cut and pasted the blurb from the publisher (or BGG) into the wiki space for many games.

Even more annoying is that there is currently [no way to delete orphan wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90752/allow-moderators-to-delete-orphaned-tag-wikis), so after pasting the text, the original lives on, cluttering the list.

I've raised a feature request on Meta about this: [Please complete the orphan wiki lifecycle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187072/please-complete-the-orphan-wiki-lifecycle).

Restored:

- [belote](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belote)
- [carrom](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carrom)
- [discworld-ankh-morpork](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discworld-ankh-morpork)
- [gloom](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gloom)
- [kids-of-catan](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kids-of-catan)
- [lost-cities](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lost-cities)
- [somnium](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/somnium)
- [titan](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titan)

Comment: I'm not surprised that some tags died before we ever began trying to save them.  Maybe you can crowd-source the effort by posting the oprhan wikis somewhere (waves hands :-) ) so other people can try to identify them and their original questions?

Comment: Oh yuck; no way to delete orphans?  What a pain.  (Apparently I do not have enough rep to see the orphans. :-( )

Comment: @Monica Cellio - yeah, the lifecycle for tag orphans is woefully incomplete. I'm raising a general meta question for it now, but I wouldn't hold your breath. I'll have a think about getting the text to some more visible location.

Comment: on publicizing the wikis, if there are enough people with the rep who are willing/able to help, maybe just point people there and ask for help.  About how many orphans are there, beyond the ones we know about from this question?

Comment: @Monica Cellio - There are about 200 orphans, although some are legitimate (tag is gone and shouldn't return), and some are low quality (cut and paste from elsewhere). There are a few really good wikis in there as well. Not sure what the rep threshold is, it would be 10,000 on SO. I've linked the list in your question and in this answer, and raised the meta feature request (see above).

Comment: Looks like either 2k (if it's a mod tool) or 4k (trusted user); can't tell from here.  Either way, I've got work to do to get there. :-)  Thanks for raising on MSO!

Comment: Thanks for your work on this!  BTW, the Titan question was mine so it was easy for me to find.  I restored the tag to the question (recreating the tag).  If I wrote the wiki (can't remember) I might have used the phrase "monster slugathon" -- just mentioning that in case it helps with ID.  It's also possible that the wiki wasn't worth saving and could be recreated; it's been too long and I don't recall what it said.

Comment: @Monica Cellio - You're welcome. :) I've restored the Titan wiki using your hint. Feel free to review, and expand if you like: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titan. I've decided to do the obvious good wikis by hand, since it looks like the vast majority are either cut/pastes from elsewhere (which is against our policy), or are too brief to be worth my time to restore.

Comment: @Monica Cellio - What game is this (you wrote the text)? _This Avalon Hill game for 2-6 players is a game of conquest. Players start with two units and can end up with up to 12 (or more if they defeat other players and take their counters). All units may move each turn, and when a unit moves into a hex it can recruit monsters to fight with it -- if it has a recruiter native to that terrain. There's a limit on unit size, so as they grow players must split them into smaller units. If two enemy units meet they must fight; the fight is conducted on tactical terrain maps using hand-to-hand..._

Comment: Oh, that's Titan. :-)