# Game specific tags

Tags: feature-request, tagging, tags

Stackoverflow model disallow user from creating tags belove some quite high reputation level. But this particular site really need specific tags for more or less popular games. I would like to propose to introduce some tags proposing mechanism, because right now there are so many untagged questions and this number will be just rising.

Comment: why the downvote? If you don't like the idea then please explain why.

Answer (score 4):

This [is by design](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/930/are-tags-mysteriously-disappearing), and is unlikely to be implemented.

Less popular game tags can be saved by users with even zero reputation by asking a question about the same game that currently has an [untagged](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) status. Feel free to [take up the mantle](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/942/lets-save-our-tags), just note in the question that it needs retagging, and please link to the other question about the same game so the tag isn't purged in 6 months.

Comment: how do I note? just leaving a comment?

Comment: @0lukasz0, You can leave a comment or just make it the last line of the question (since it will require editing anyway)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a reasonable concern. It seems likely to me that a new user will have a question about a game for which there is no tag, and may struggle to find the [untagged](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag.

Incidentally Arqade (the gaming stack exchange site) has got the auto-deletion of single use tags turned off: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5379/3958

Comment: you cannot tag a question with untagged, the site will report an error box explaining as much. It is still a concern, because a user cannot create a question without a tag, but probably cannot find the proper tag (if the game doesn't exist), hopefully the will resort to mistaking instead of not asking the question.

Comment: @user1873 Thanks, I didn't know that. Also of interest is that you can't create tags from the mobile site (even as a user with enough reputation)