# What do we do about questions that had their game tag purged and now it's not clear what game they are about?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

I recently came across [Should you ever deploy your blank at a position other than an edge in Epigo?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/6247/3389), which seems like a decent question. However, it lacks a game tag. As best I can tell, it had one at one point, which was automatically purged from the site (see [Are tags mysteriously disappearing?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/930/3389)).

I'd like to be helpful and add the tag back in, then add a tag wiki so that it doesn't get purged again. But the thing is, I have no clue what game it is. Other questions lacking a game tag usually have the name of the game in the title or the body of the question, but not this one.

While I hope that someone can identify this game, I'd also like to ask: what do you do in general if you come across an old question that no longer has any information about the game?

Also, do we do anything different with closed questions? I've come across [Big or small team members in Heroclix?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/7597/3389), which also lacks a game tag or any identifying information, but is closed and unlikely to be reoponed. Do we just leave these questions or do something else?

<sub>I suppose I could create an [identify-this-game](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) question about these games, but that seems a bit overkill.</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ideally, we find some way to figure out what the missing information is and edit it - into the question, not just the tag. Pretty much the same thing we'd do to any post we discover to be missing information!

Note that the [untagged](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag description basically says this:

> This tag appears every now and then, when tags are deleted off of a question by automatic means. It means what it says, and indicates that those questions need editing.

Ways to do that:

- look for a copy on archive.org
- google bits of the question (and answers)
- ask the OP (if they're still around)
- ask here, or in chat, or even an identify-this-game if you really care
- go hunt in SEDE (I'm not sure if deleted tags are preserved there?)

For [Should you ever deploy your blank at a position other than an edge in Epigo?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6247/should-you-ever-deploy-your-blank-at-a-position-other-than-an-edge), based on "blank Epigon" in the question, I quickly found [Epigo](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/103368/epigo), which has pictures that look like the ones in the question.

For closed questions... eh. There's not any need to actively seek them out, but if the question hasn't been automatically deleted (which happens eventually without upvoted answers), and if it might get reopened, we can fix them if we notice them.

For [Big or small team members](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7597/big-or-small-team-members), given that it was closed so long after it was posted, I suspect it was closed purely because the game name was missing from it, so no one could tell what it was about. That's *definitely* not good! But it has an accepted answer from someone who clearly understood what it was asking, so I went ahead and reopened.

And that one is [Heroclix](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/3439/heroclix), which I found by googling "superman board game hulk damage points figures".